# How to properly transform csv file into a txt file

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I'm using a dataframe from a psychology experience in R and i would like to transform the datas into a text file.

I've tried some solutions given in this forum and i have succeded in separated all the datas in each cell of the dataframe. However, now the column doesn't correpond to their column names.

i have used this code :

```
with open("pathname/tab_resultats_txt.csv") as my_input_file :
    with open("tab_resultats_3.txt", "w") as outfile:
        for line in csv.reader(my_input_file, delimiter = ";"):
            outfile.write(' '.join(line)+'\n')
```

Is their a simple way to modify my code in order to acheive what i want?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a sample of your data and what the output should look like.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is not clear enough. I finaly found a way to do it with this code :  'df=pd.read_csv("path_file/tab.csv", sep = ";")
tfile = open('data_sujets_text.txt', 'a')
tfile.write(df.to_string())
tfile.close()'